# Area 51 Graph Weird

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, area-51

The graph for Area 51 on the mobile web is very weird. Google on Galaxy S2. When making text as small as I can without exiting the window (default), the graph lines look weird. The lines that stand out are weird.

Why? Because usually, all the lines you can see can make borders of rectangles that are the same size. Here's the screen shot:
[image]

The graph is under the followers subtitle. The three lines that stand out kinda look like this:
[image]

Only three lines come up in weird positions, not making any nice, pretty rectangles of the same size. So why do only those three lines come up even though they don't make equivalent rectangles nor appear in the "right" spots?

Perfect rectangles can be seen in this close-up photo:
[image]

Comment: Area51 does not have mobile theme.

Comment: What do you mean by "mobile theme"? Do you not like my lines in Picture 2? I used paint on my desktop to help make them... They can't be ***that*** bad.

Comment: Different view designed for mobile devices, for example on other sites you can access it by clicking "mobile" in the footer. That's what the [tag:mobile-web] is for, and it's not relevant for Area 51 since it simply doesn't have such a thing, hence I removed the tag.

Comment: But still, it's weird...

Comment: Personally I can't see anything weird, but maybe a dev can so I'm not downvoting this one.

Comment: @Downvoter... Explain yourself!

Comment: "*When making text as small as I can*" Is there an advantage to doing so with the text, or is it useful in some way? If not, then there is no real issue here. Scenarios within design which users wouldn't or shouldn't be doing are not usually catered for - especially as web design is often a compromise of things. Like saying "when I quint my eyes the site is a bit fuzzy"...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oddities in drawing lines are just something that naturally happens when you try to cram a full-width screen onto a tiny mobile device. It's trying to draw 1px lines at specific increments across a pre-defined width of a box. When you shrink that, those *x* and *y* coordinates become decimals due to translation. Basically, the darker the line appears, the closer to an exact integer *x* or *y* coordinate it is when it gets shrunk down to its new size.

For what it's worth, you can reproduce the exact same thing if you were to zoom out on a normal browser:

[image: Shrink the graph!]

Bottom line: The graph is meant to be displayed at 100% zoom **on a normal desktop browser**.

Comment: That answers my question! Thanks!